# MTG Android App for Cataloging

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I recently began using tappedout.net to keep track of my cards and I couldn't help but wonder if there was an Android app that fulfilled the same purpose. Might you assist me in my search?

Comment: Despite the fact product recommendations are ordinarily not facilitated here, I'm keen on keeping this one around: MTG card cataloguing is a critical issue for MTG users that often has no good answer, and the actual set of products available is extremely small.

Comment: @doppelgreener While this is an important issue, it's not within a scope of our format, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. I was looking into how I could catalogue my own collection at a decent pace, and manually typing in card names just wasn't going to cut it. I have a Windows + Android device, so I went searching too.

Since you're using TappedOut, it would be remiss of me to not mention that TappedOut has its own Android app: the [**TappedOut MTG Companion**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tappedout&hl=en_GB) which includes a "visual collection updater": in theory, it lets you lay out your cards nice and neatly, photograph several of them at once, then add them to a collection. I say "in theory" because I've not yet been able to use it successfully — I've just gotten an error when I try.

The app I went with to scan my own collection was [**Delver Lens**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=delverslab.delverlens&hl=en_GB). Out of every Android app, it is the only one that scans cards *and* lets me output the list to TappedOut. (In fact, it's even got a custom export format prepared *just* for TappedOut!) It does one-by-one card scanning, and it's a little finnicky but easy enough to get the hang of. Overall I was able to catalogue ~140 cards in a few minutes using this, then export them to my TappedOut inventory just fine.

All Windows and other Android applications I'd found didn't give me an exportable list, *or* only existed to check market prices. Accordingly, I have *zero* other apps to mention that perform this purpose.

---

<sub>I have no affiliation with any of the products I've mentioned beyond being a ordinary user, and I do not gain anything from recommending them.</sub>

Comment: Delver Lens developer here - Delver Lens can scan multiple cards but is usually not useful since you spend time laying them on the table.